# Is it possible to pause a Unity WebPlayer using javascript, without changing anything to the build?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I want the game to freeze when some javascript event happens (for instance the webplayer goes out of view, a button is clicked on the page). I however would like it to be a solely javascript solution because I don't want to bug people about making a different build. However if it's not possible as a javascript-only solution, that's fine too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is with the UnityPlayer SendMessage method. You can also call javascript on the page from your game with the Application.ExternalCall function.

There is a page in the manual on how to do this : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html